# From inside iframe want to get all iframe class name (each Iframe has a different class name)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

1. index HTML file have multiple Iframes
2. From inside iframe want to get all iframe class name (each Iframe has a different class name).
3. If iframe has xyz class name than fire function.

I tried with below code,

```
var iframes= parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
console.log(iframes[0].getAttribute("class"));
```

problem: above code is working getting iframe class, based on index[0], if i want get 2nd index i have to iframes[1].getAttribute("class").

it is possible to get all class dynamically and compare with xyz class fire function

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var iframes= parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for(var i=0;i<iframes.length;i++){
    if(iframes[i].getAttribute("class") == 'xyz'){
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: wc @raghuak if this was helpful then please mark as a true an answer to help others. :)